# How to refresh the HTML file which is in NSDocumentDirectory? (more than one time)

Tags: objective-c, pdf-generation

I am using **HTML** file to **generate pdf** file in **DocumentDirectory**. Every time I need to refresh
(with new image which is having same name in html file) **HTML file** when below method is calling.

Right now i am doing like this, but it is refreshing for only first time(when ever i am calling this method)

```
-(void)RefreshingHTML
{
// fetching path
NSArray* deletepath_forDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* deletedocumentsDirectoryfiles = [deletepath_forDirectory objectAtIndex:0];`

// Delete HTML file in DocumentDirectory
NSString *deleteHTMLPath = [deletedocumentsDirectoryfiles stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"HTML_Demo.html"];
NSString *deletePDFPath = [deletedocumentsDirectoryfiles stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"HTML_Demo.pdf"];
NSLog(@"delete HTML file Path : %@",deleteHTMLPath);
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:deleteHTMLPath]) {

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:deleteHTMLPath error:NULL];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:deletePDFPath error:NULL];
}
// fetching HTML file from supporting files
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"HTML_Demo" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSArray* path_forDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDirectory = [path_forDirectory objectAtIndex:0];

// saving HTML file to DocumentDirectory
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:pathURL];
[data writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/HTML_Demo.html",documentsDirectory] atomically:YES];

// Fetching HTML file from DocumentDirectory
NSString *HTMLPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"HTML_Demo.html"];
NSLog(@"delete HTML file Path: %@",HTMLPath);
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:HTMLPath]) {

    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:HTMLPath];

    // Converting HTML to PDF
    self.PDFCreator = [NDHTMLtoPDF createPDFWithURL:targetURL
                                     pathForPDF:[@"~/Documents/HTML_Demo.pdf" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]
                                       delegate:self
                                       pageSize:kPaperSizeA4
                                        margins:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 5, 90, 5)];
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL may be loading from cache.  In NDHTMLtoPDF.m, look in viewDidLoad:

Instead of: [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.URL]];

Try using the constructor that allows you to set cachePolicy:

NSURLRequest requestWithURL:<#(NSURL *)#> cachePolicy:<#(NSURLRequestCachePolicy)#> timeoutInterval:<#(NSTimeInterval)#>

This policy might work better for your needs: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData

Or you could just add something to your URL's querystring so it's never found in cache (e.g., an index or timestamp).